# Create a list from list template from list template gallery folder

Tags: development

Hi I need to create list programatically from list template which is in inside folder of List Template Gallery
(List Template -> folder -> template.stp.)

Answer (score 3):

The following function will create list from template programmatically.. **But you don't need to put .stp files in Folder, I'm not sure if the stp is in folder.. the following code will work or not, but definitely it will work if the stp file is in List Template root.**

```
public static SPList CreateListByTemplate(SPWeb web, string listName, string description, string displayName, string templateName)
    {
        SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList(listName);

        if (list == null)
        {
            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

            var lstTemp = web.Site.GetCustomListTemplates(web);

            var template = lstTemp[templateName];

            var listId = web.Lists.Add(listName, description, template);

            list = web.Lists[listId];
            list.Title = displayName;
            list.Update();

            web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
        }

        return list;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

You don't need to deploy Stp files programmatically, simple make an empty Module add the stp file in this module and Elements.xml file should look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="ListTemplates" Path="ListTemplates" Url="_catalogs/lt">
    <File Path="StpFileName.stp" Url="StpFileName.stp" Type="GhostableInLibrary">
      <Property Name="Title">List Template Title</Property>
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Add this module to the features which deploys everything..

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am adding the the stp file on activation of the feature (Feature stapling). this creates the folder on the List Template gallery and upload the stp in it.

Comment: See the update in answer

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct to close the question :)

Comment: How can i make list from stp file using CSOM ?